# Does DynamoDB charge for the read/write capacity Input set-up for a table or, only for the usage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does DynamoDB charge for the read/write capacity Input I set-up for a table or, only for when I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html) in documentation answers your question pretty extensively.

Write capacity units are only consumed for writing and removing individual items:

> The following describes how DynamoDB write operations consume write
> capacity units:
>
> PutItem—writes a single item to a table. If an item with the same
> primary key exists in the table, the operation replaces the item. For
> calculating provisioned throughput consumption, the item size that
> matters is the larger of the two.
>
> UpdateItem—modifies a single item in
> the table. DynamoDB considers the size of the item as it appears
> before and after the update. The provisioned throughput consumed
> reflects the larger of these item sizes.
>
> DeleteItem—removes a single item from a table.
> The provisioned throughput consumption is based on the size of the
> deleted item.
>
> BatchWriteItem—writes up to 25 items to one or more
> tables. For example, if BatchWriteItem
> writes a 500 byte item and a 3.5 KB item, DynamoDB will calculate the
> size as 5 KB (1 KB + 4 KB), not 4 KB (500 bytes + 3.5 KB).

RCUs are only consumed when you read elements from a table:

> The following describes how DynamoDB read operations consume read
> capacity units:
>
> GetItem—reads a single item from a table. For example, if you read an item that is 3.5 KB, DynamoDB rounds the
> item size to 4 KB. If you read an item of 10 KB, DynamoDB rounds the
> item size to 12 KB.
>
> BatchGetItem—reads up to 100 items, from one or
> more tables. For example, if BatchGetItem reads a 1.5 KB item and a 6.5
> KB item, DynamoDB will calculate the size as 12 KB (4 KB + 8 KB), not
> 8 KB (1.5 KB + 6.5 KB).
>
> Query—reads multiple items that have the same
> partition key value. For example, suppose
> your query returns 10 items whose combined size is 40.8 KB. DynamoDB
> rounds the item size for the operation to 44 KB. If a query returns
> 1500 items of 64 bytes each, the cumulative size is 96 KB.
>
> Scan—reads
> all of the items in a table. DynamoDB considers the size of the items
> that are evaluated, not the size of the items returned by the scan.

**UPDATE**

To make it clear. You pay money no matter how much of provisioned RCUs/WCUs you use, but you do not spend RCUs/WCUs on table creation/deletion.

Comment: Understood. So you mean unless and until there are read/write queries done on DynamoDB table, I will not be charged irrespective of the fact that I had set the number of read/write capacity units while creating the table?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You are not charged for table creation/deletion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Ivan. That really helped.

Comment: This is entirely incorrect. If this was the case everyone would just allocate a massive amount of capacity units and then only pay for what they actually use. In actuality, when you allocate DynamoDB capacity there are server resources behind the scenes that are created to handle that amount of capacity. Those resources exist regardless if you use the capacity or not. You get charged (billed) for the capacity you allocate, not the capacity you end up using.

Comment: There are two things here. You pay money for provisioned capacity with money and you "pay" with RCU/WCUs for each request. So yes, you are right that you pay money no matter how much resources are you using, but you don't spend RCU/WCUs only for reading/writing and not for tables creation/deletion.

Comment: The majority of the answer is immaterial to the question, which was not about a "charge for setup/creation," but was about a charge applying based on the read/write capacity specified when creating a table... so the correct answer is simply "Yes.  You are charged for the capacity, beginning at the point when you create the table, whether or not the capacity is actually used, because the charge is not for usage, it is for the capacity you are purchasing."

Comment: Well I also had the same confusion that if AWS don't charge you for the RCUs and WCUs that you allocate while creating table but only for the RCUs and WCUs among them that you end up using, then,wouldn't people allocate maximum RCUs and WCUs while creating table to avoid future latency ? Thanks @MarkB for clearing that I will get charged for the RCUs and WCUs that I allocate. I am very new to AWS and was very confused with this.

Comment: Does DynamoDB charge or throttle when you are reading for a key which is not present in the dynamodb table?